# Full SSH proxy over a reverse SSH connection

Tags: ssh, reverse-proxy, ssh-tunnel

There are tools like `sshuttle` that allow proxying of all traffic through an outbound SSH connection. In our case, we can only SSH into the server, and would like to then proxy *all* outbound traffic over the inbound SSH connection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using ssh port forwarding.In this scenario let's say you can ssh login into b, the command 
 `ssh -L2001:HostD:143 user@HostB` will use the ssh tunnel to forward all the outbound traffic from your port 2001 to the port 143 of the HostD , And as you can see ,you can replace HostD by by localhost ,that would made it instead forward the traffic to the port 143 of HostB
[image]

Image credit goes to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKrO5WABdoY&t=251s